# Run-time errors when attempting to pull a data table from UPS.com using VBA

Tags: vba

I have the following code so far. I keep getting Run-time error 91 at the following line:

```
Range("B1").Value = upsClass(0).textContent
```

Here is the full code I have so far. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub extract()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = False
IE.Navigate2 "https://www.ups.com/WebTracking/track?loc=en_US&WT.svl=PNRO_L1"

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set html = IE.document
Set upsClass = html.getElementsByClassName("dataTable")

IE.document.all("trackNums").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
IE.document.all("track.x").Click

Range("B1").Value = upsClass(0).textContent

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Cell A1 contains a tracking number for a package and I am attempting to grab the shipment progress table and paste the data into B1.

I now get run-time error 70 Permission Denied when trying    ?TypeName (upsClass(0)) in the Immediate Pane and am not sure why

Comment: What does `html.getElementsByClassName("dataTable")` return?

Comment: It should be grabbing a data table from UPS.com that shows the shipment progress.

Comment: Sure. But is that what it *actually* does? Runtime error 91 suggests that `upsClass` is `Nothing`, or `upsClass(0)` is `Nothing`.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure. There is only 1 class on the page that is named dataTable. I am relatively new to VBA, so how would I go about checking exactly what it is grabbing? It is also attempting to grab it from a collapsed div that uses javascript to expand. Could this be why it might not be grabbing anything?

Comment: Select the line that's blowing up, hit F9 to place a breakpoint. Now run the macro and when the editor stops on the breakpoint you can use the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) and/or the *locals* toolwindows to find out. e.g. `?upsClass Is Nothing` in the immediate pane will print `True` if `upsClass` holds no object reference, `False` if it does. If it's `True` then you need to fix the line of code that's setting it. Maybe `"dataTable"` is wrong? Maybe it's case-sensitive? IDK, just throwing ideas.

Comment: So the immediate pane returns as False when I enter    ?upsClass is Nothing, so it seems like it is grabbing something.

Comment: how about `?upsClass(0).textContent`?

Comment: That gives me run-time error 70 saying permission is denied

Comment: Huh, that's rather unexpected. Does `?TypeName(upsClass(0))` print an actual type name, `Empty`, or raises a runtime error (70 or 91)?

Comment: `?TypeName(upsClass(0))` gives the same run-time 70 error.

Comment: Are you sure your element is the first in the collection? Can you view the upsClass collection elements in the immediate window? Can you declare upsClass appropriately?

Comment: If you goto the UPS page and view the source then you will not find either `class="datatable"` or even `datatable` with a regular search. Why do you think this class name exists on the page?

Comment: I am trying to just pull the entire table. The class does exist on the page, you just need to have tracked a shipment. I am not sure how I can view the collection elements in the immediate window.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace:

```
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
```

With:

```
Do While IE.Busy and IE.ReadyState <> 4 then
    DoEvents
Loop
```

It is mandatory to use this loop not only after navigating, but also after clicking an element.

In this code:

```
Set html = IE.document
Set upsClass = html.getElementsByClassName("dataTable")

IE.document.all("trackNums").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
IE.document.all("track.x").Click

Range("B1").Value = upsClass(0).textContent
```

you can refer to `IE.document` as `html` in all cases. Try not using GetElementsByClassName. I can't say I'm 100% certain, but this method rather doesn't work in VBA, at least doesn't work in my environment. You can use:

```
Dim htmlEle1 As IHTMLElement

For each htmlEle1 in html.getElementsByTagName("someTag")
    If htmlEle1.ClassName = "dataTable" then
        'do stuff, htmlEle1.textContent can be extracted
        Exit for 'only first item with this class is needed
    End IF
Next htmlEle1
```

Also you split the part when `upsClass` is set and the other part when you extract `upsClass(0).textContent` by using `.click`. It could happen that element doesn't exist anymore after clicking.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a shot and see how it works.